# Cannot return boolean using JPQL in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jpql

I have the following JPQL query in my repository and when I run its SQL version (our database is PostgreSQL), it works properly. However, when I run this JPQL, it returns only the records that has True value. I think the problem may be related to JPQL and wanted to ask. So, is there any problem regarding to this query?

```
@Query("SELECT p.uuid as uid, " +
       "CASE WHEN m.uuid IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as d FROM Product p " +
        "LEFT JOIN Menu m on m.productUuid = p.uuid ")
List<ProductMenu> findAllProduct();
```

Comment: Is `ProductMenu` an entity, a custom object, an interface ?

Comment: `ProductMenu` is interface and I implement necessary setter and getter methods in it properly.

Comment: OK, so your aliases match the projection fields, right ? (must be `getUid()` and `getD()`)

Comment: Yess, exactly... I just want to know that if the usage of CASE with boolean is correct or not. The rest can be solved easily if it is true.

Comment: i tried like this

`SELECT i.id as id, CASE WHEN i.itemCode IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END as active FROM Item i`

interface has two things and **its working find**

`Integer getId()`
`boolean getActive()`

Comment: Yes the query is fine. I'm afraid we cannot help more without further information. Please provide a minimal reproductible example.

Comment: Do you have primitive boolean or its wrapper in projection declaration? I mean `getd()` method

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisRashid Thanks a lot. Then there is no problem regarding to my JPQL. Thanks also other friends.